# Is there any way that we can pass the parameter or argument file to pipeline in data fusion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I want to pass the argument list to data fusion pipeline . It's more like parameter file that is used in informatica tool .
Is there any way I can achieve this .

Answer (score 0):

You can set arguments to a pipeline through [HTTP requests](https://github.com/data-integrations/argument-setter) or from a [Bigquery table](https://github.com/data-integrations/google-cloud/blob/develop/docs/BigQueryArgumentSetter-action.md).
You can also check [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/reusable-pipeline) to create reusable pipelines.